# How to create Global user menu in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

In my master page (_Layout.cshtml) I have user menu control like:-

HTML:

```
 <div id="menucontainer">
  <li class="adminPanel"><a class = "FacilityUpdate" href="#">Rename Facility Test</a></li>
</div>

 <div id="dialog" title="Rename Facility">
        <div id="grid" style="overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;">
            @Html.Action("GridViewPartial") @*This creating problem*@

        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
 $('.FacilityUpdate').click(function (event) {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            event.preventDefault();
 });
```

GridviewPartial : This partial view present in Layout view

```
@{
var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "GridView";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "controllername", Action = "GridViewPartial" };
    settings.KeyFieldName = "lng_id";
    settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
    settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = false;
    settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = false;
    settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;
    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.SettingsCookies.Enabled = true;

    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "s_str_pstrname";
        column.Caption = "Source Facility";
            column.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(8);

    });
    });
   }
   @grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

**Problem :**

When i was on default view ie. Layout.cshtml then popup will open with devexpress grid with data.
But when i move to another view and click on Menuitem then devexpress grid create this error :

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 07:55:53 UTC


 Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
 Line: 0
 Char: 0
 Code: 0
  URI: http://localhost:4640/PlatAnodeSurvey
```

How i can create a global popup so that i will click on any view and then click in menuitem popup will open with binded grid.
Here Devexpress grid is my limitation because i am using devexpress throughout my project.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where did you place your link `click` handler?

Comment: Please check jquery code..

Comment: I mean where did you place that code? Is it in separate file, inline? Is it inside `$(document).ready(function() { }`?

Comment: It is placed in layout.cshtml.No it is not in ready function

Comment: Try to put this code into the `$(document).ready`.

Comment: try specifying the controller in the call to @Html.Action("GridViewPartial")

Comment: Yes i tried it as @Html.Action("GridViewPartial","controllername").In this case i am getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a partial view with div

2) on click on of link call the below generic jquery script

a) Set URL of your controller and action in the script
  b) you pass parameter so that it will generic

```
function showPopUP(paramValue) {
        $('#popupDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 800,
            height: "auto",
            maxWidth: 800,
            resizable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            title: 'Generic Popup',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                url = "../popupcontroller/ActionName?Pname=" + paramValue;
                $(this).load(url);
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }).dialog('open');
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Did you used here devexpress ? My problem is related with Devexpress grid,otherwise i am able to open popup on any view.

Answer (score -2):

Jquery library for Menu creation

http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Use Jquery accordion control
with this you can create slidding menu's with different views
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/